# Using 32-bit and 64-bit Python - "NameError: global name 'numpy' etc. is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, 64-bit

I was having a memory error in Python with a program, I found out I had to upgrade my Python to 64 bit. I did that. I then copied all the files from the Lib/site-packages folder of the Python 32 bit and pasted it in the 64 bit folder. I did this so I wouldn't have to install the modules again for my program.

I ran the program and got the following error:

> NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

And yes, I had `import numpy` in the program

I think the problem is that I have to actually `pip install numpy` inside of the 64 bit Python (even though I copied the exact same Lib/site-packages from 32 bit to 64 bit) using cmd. If that is the problem, how do I specifically `pip install` inside of the 64 bit Python folder rather than the default 32 bit folder?

Otherwise, any suggestions?

Comment: If `import numpy` succeeded, there's no way you would get that error.

Comment: What is the OS? Windows?

Comment: @Nae yes, Windows 10

Comment: *"I then copied all the files from the Scripts folder of the Python 32 bit and pasted it in the 64 bit folder.  I did this so I wouldn't have to install the modules again for my program."* I suspect this won't work.  If you have have a new python installation, you should install the python packages that you need using the usual installation methods.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  
Ok, makes sense. How do I install in the 64-bit Python though?

Answer (score 1):

> I then copied all the files from the Scripts folder of the Python 32
>   bit and pasted it in the 64 bit folder. I did this so I wouldn't have
>   to install the modules again for my program.

That wasn't a good idea. There are executables in the Scripts folder that are not the same for 32-bit and 64-bit Python. You have to do `pip install` separately for 32-bit and 64-bit Python. Any DLL involved in the install will not be the same for both versions, in fact 64-bit Python will not even see a 32-bit DLL.

Do it the long way. I know that's a drag but taking shortcuts is likely to lead to baffling errors.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. How do I install in the 64-bit Python though?

Comment: Return the Scripts folder to the way it was before you graunched it. Then do `pip install` from inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

For windows <kbd>Shift-Right-Click</kbd> on your 64-bit installation folder that has `python.exe` and select `Open command window here`. Then type `python.exe -m pip install numpy` in there and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What this does is that it calls 64-bit python's pip to install numpy instead.

Comment: Great solution but I get the following message: >Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages

Comment: @TheRealG Are you're certainly in 64-bit installation folder not 32-bit installation folder?

Comment: yes, when I open the Powershell cmd it starts with the following line: > PS C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python36> which is definitely the 64-bit version because the 32 bit version is Python36-32

Comment: @TheRealG I don't know then. Perhaps add 64-bit in environment variables path or uninstall 32-bit python using _standard_ uninstallation unless further needed.

Comment: @TheRealG Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043267/7032856) as well?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows I use always this:

1. Rename the pip.exe to pip64.exe for example
2. Add python folder to Sys path if not exists.
3. You can use "pip64 install package_name"